# Error forwarding request when running Localstack in docker

Tags: docker, localstack

I am trying to run localstack in docker and getting the following error:

> Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready localstack_1
>   | 2019-09-08T12:32:52:ERROR:localstack.services.generic_proxy: Error
>   forwarding request: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4561):
>   Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
>   Connection refused',)) Traceback (most recent call last): localstack_1
>   |   File
>   "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py",
>   line 160, in _new_conn localstack_1               |
>   (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw) localstack_1
>   |   File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-pack

I am not sure what I have done wrong, I have localstack running from an image:

```
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    #container_name: app_localstack
    ports:
      - '4563-4599:4563-4599'
      - '8055:8080'
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sns,sqs
      - HOSTNAME=localstack
      - DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2
      - DEBUG=1
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
    networks:
      - localdevenv
```

Using information I found online I then run a short-lived bandsintown/alpine to create the necessary SQS topics and queues.

```
  localstack-configurator:
    build:
      context: ./dockerImgs/localstack
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: localstack-configurator
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2
    depends_on:
      - localstack
    networks:
      - localdevenv
```

It appears as if the queues are correctly created and the subscription work which is the weirdest part of the whole thing.

This is running the latest version of Docker on MacOS Sierra.